Checkmarks issue in JSP
Check marks is flagging cross site scripting issue in the below code. can you please help me in resolving the issue.
Code in JSP:
<a href="javascript:getData('${sta.Date}','${sta.EndDate}');">
<fmt:formatDate value="${sta.EndDate}" pattern="MMM - yy " />
<c:out value="${caa.selected.number} - ${caa.selected.number} " />
<c:if test="${not empty sta.statement and  sta.statement!='' and sta.statement != ' '}">
<c:out value=" - ${sta.statement}" />
</c:if>
</a>

code in Javascript file:
function getData(date, endDate) {
var element1 = document.getElementsByName("selectedDate")[0];
element1.value = date;
var element2 = document.getElementsByName("selectedEndDate")[0];
element2.value = endDate;
formSubmit("showReport");   
}


I tried to sanitize the input with the below function
function sanitize(string) {
const map = {
'&': '&amp;',
'<': '&lt;',
'>': '&gt;',
'"': '&quot;',
"'": '&#x27;',
"/": '&#x2F;',
};
const reg = /[&<>"'/]/ig;
return string.replace(reg, (match)=>(map[match]));
}

but Issue not resolved


I don't see any checkboxes or inputs of any kind in your code.

The issue the checkmarks is showing is at this line:

Thie below is the issue:The method "javascript:getData embeds untrusted data in generated output with BinaryExpr, at line 114 of \main.jsp.
This untrusted data is embedded into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code

Why are you using an anchor element for non-navigation actions? Perhaps it's the javascript:... part causing the error. A button would be more appropriate.

This is the very old project and this code is very old and written by somebody else. Can you show me the code how we can change the anchor to button in my code.
<fmt:formatDate value="${sta.EndDate}" pattern="MMM - yy " />
<c:out value="${caa.selected.number} - ${caa.selected.number} " />
<c:if test="${not empty sta.statement and  sta.statement!='' and sta.statement != ' '}">
<c:out value=" - ${sta.statement}" />
</c:if>


Have your read the documentation for button and addEventListener?

The sanitization should be done on server.

@mykaf The button type submitt do you mean? The button doesn't work either because the code has XSS valnerability. It should be fixed by sanitizing the variable in EL not the input fields.
